# Phantomjs Behat form field not found when executing in my server

Tags: phantomjs, behat, mink

everyone, could I have some help please ?

I try to run a test with Behat/Mink and Phantomjs. It works locally without Phantomjs, but not on my server.

When I launch my tests, I've got this problem :

```
 @javascript
 Scenario: Searching for a page that does NOT exist                             
Given I am on "http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Accueil_principal" 
When I fill in "searchInput" with "Glory Driven Development"                 
  Form field with id|name|label|value "searchInput" not found.
```

My settings in behat.yml is as following

```
phantomjs:
context:
      class:  'FeatureContext'
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      goutte: ~
      selenium2:
        wd_host: "http://localhost:8643/wd/hub"
        capabilities:
            proxy:
               proxyType: direct
```

My test is as following

```
@javascript 
Scenario: Searching for a page that does NOT exist
Given I am on "http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/WikipC3%A9dia:Accueil_principal"
When I fill in "searchInput" with "Glory Driven Development"
And I press "searchButton"
Then I should see "Search results"
```

I can't understand why it says : "Form field with id|name|label|value "searchInput" not found". I have launched phantomjs and even selenium.

Does someone has an idea ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was trying same scenario today.

Driver is complaining about not finding the element. So I debug a bit the test case and found that the page browsed by driver was different than the one expected.

When the driver does: `$this->getSession()->getPage()`. Be sure you are in the expected page and receiving expected html.